# Jquery stop image blink before fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below given jquery function to show images in lightbox image carousal. It is working fine  except, when the user click on next navigation button to see next image, the present image blinks once and then  next image is shown. I want to remove this image blink before fade out and want to achieve smooth fade out effect. How to do this?

```
function view_post(id, nav) {
    var viewer = $("#post-viewer");
    var userid = '';
    var page = '';
    if (nav != undefined && nav) {
        var lists = $(".post-list");
        userid = lists.data('userid');
        page = lists.data('page');
    }
    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
        url : baseUrl + 'post/load?id=' + id,
        data : {userid:userid,page:page},
        success: function(t) {
            viewer.find('.content').html(t);
            viewer.fadeIn();
            viewer.find('.close').click(function() {
                viewer.fadeOut();
                viewer.find('.content').html('');
                return false;
            })
            viewer.find('.cover').click(function() {
                viewer.fadeOut();
                viewer.find('.content').html('');
    var url = baseUrl;
    var title = 'Title';
if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
                return false;
            })
            hideLoader();
            reload_init();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please also share some sample HTML (including images, CSS, scripts, et cetera) so we can reproduce the problem you're describing. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you are trying to `fadeIn` the image which seems to be already visible, which means the opacity will alter from 0->100 for the fade in, thus causing the blink.

If you alter the following line in your `navigate_post` routine, you should be all set..

```
navigate_post(l, type) {
    ...
    container.find('.image').hide();
    container.find('.image-' + imageToLoad).show();
    return false;
}
```

i.e. `.fadeIn()`->`.show()`

Comment: what to amend in my original code can u explain please. i use  <a class="nav-left" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page1', '/post/<?php echo $next?>'); return view_post('<?php echo $next?>', true)" ><i class="icons icon-arrow-left"></i></a>

Comment: `/styles/default/js/script.js?v=1.3` around line `#430`

Comment: @Mark glad I could help out; please remember to mark my post as the answer to your question; if it was helpful :)